# Why is this option trade considered over the counter

Tags: call-options

In this [article](http://www.futuresmag.com/2015/02/15/out-money-call-ratio-spreads)

the author says:

```
    Since June 24, crude prices halved while CVX has dropped only 20%. 
   SPY has risen slightly less than 3% during that time period.
   What’s a good options strategy in light of all of this information? 

    A 1X2 **over-the-counter** call ratio spread
```

Why does this trade need to be an over the counter trade? It is a standard call option trade with standard contract size of 100 shares. So why is it over the counter as opposed to being traded on an exchange?

Comment: From the looks of the article, I wouldn't be surprised if they didn't include the term just because it sounded 'cool'.

Comment: Thanks. I guess you don't think the article is any good?:)

Comment: I wouldn't say that, maybe take it with a grain of salt.  He definitely points out some ideas, but I'm not entirely sure whether this writer is an actual trader or just a guy who gets paid to write articles about trading.  (in which case he has to 'make them interesting')

Comment: SPY and CVX both offer exchange traded options so this trade would not be done on the OTC.